# How to pause and resume a Flutter app to test automated logout behaviour in background

Tags: flutter

I am building an app in which the user is logged out automatically if the app-state is paused (goes into the background), after a specified amount of time (like 30sec).

Now I would love to create an automated integration test for this behaviour (if possible) to check if the auto-logout is correctly working. For this, I need to pause the Flutter app (home button?) and restart it after 31 secs.

Can you think of a way how this is might be implemented?

Comment: Testing time is rarely a good idea.
You need to abstract the time.
You can trigger via method or parametrized time.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I know its not optimal and I already have a widget test using a fake timer for the service that is handling this scenario. It was a wish from business to simulate the prod environment as much as possible for the integration tests. However, I will probably stick to widget testing with fake lifecycle events then.

Comment: You shouldn't have any worries then. Do a Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 30))